# How to avoid Java window flicker with border while resizing?

Tags: java, swing, resize, flicker, window-resize

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createMainWindow();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createMainWindow() {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Flicker Teste");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.add(new MainPanel());
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    public MainPanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red)); //If I comment this line the diagonal is streteched on the border.
        setBackground(Color.green);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 5000, 5000);
    }
}
```

MainPanel.java

These two file are the code to reproduce the resize flicker bug.
When you do a fast resize the border is repeated resulting in a horrible flicker.
And if there is no border then the last pixel of the diagonal line which touch the edge of the window is
repeated, as if the "blank border" consists of repeating the pixels at the edge.

Someone know how to stop this horrible flickering?
I already searched for solutions, but I have found no one.

Comment: I'm actually not getting a flicker, it's just a black background in the new region when resizing to a larger size.

Comment: The code looks fine. Try closing out all other heavy duty applications you have open and see if it still happens.